# Tortoisesvn repo browser and ip addresses?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn

I am using visualsvn on my local (home) dev machine and have an svn server, on the cloud. This is on a private network and requires a vpn session to access.

So far, I have made a network share of the folder on the server where the repositories are stored. When I add a new solution, not yet under src control, I just go to add solution in visualsvn and say new project (no repository).

I've also made the server accessible over the public internet via its ip (public ip).

My question is: When using the tortoise svn rep browser, can I enter an address like so: `http://ipaddress/repository`? Or does it always have to be by hostname?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes. And if you prefer, TortoiseSVN also understands https://

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to get my network all sorted out, and my first attempt at this didn't show the repositories but I will troubleshoot.